# Opening of modal causing background page to lose event bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, binding

I have a webpage containing links to modals.

At the top of this page there is a search bar called #top-search.
In my main JS file I've attatched the event within the ready function:

```js
$('#top-search').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            window.location.href = *MySearchActionHere*('#top-search').val();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This works fine, until a modal is opened, and then it appears the event binding is lost. What could be causing this to happen?

Comment: Do you have another `#top-search` in modal?

Comment: @Satpal nope done a global search for id conflicts but none can be found!

Comment: @OliSmart has the page navigated? seems very confusing you are navigating away and also `return false;` for what not to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

Try delegating you event

```
$('body').on('keypress','#top-search',function (e) {
});
```

Comment: Just tried it, still losing it's event, thank you though.

Comment: then that means you #top-search isn't on the page